# Boost directory_iterator error: no match for operator!=

Tags: c++, boost

I'm just starting to get into the C++ boost libraries.  I'm running into an issue with directory_iterator and recursive_directory_iterator.  When I try to compile the following code, I always get a no match for operator!=.  I have also tried == to no avail.

```
const boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end();
for(boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator i(p); i != end; i++){
    if(boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(i->status())){
        cout << i->path().filename() << endl;
    }
}
```

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end()` does not define a variable `end` instead it declares a function prototype for function `end` which returns a `const boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` and does not take any arguments (Search for "C++ most vexing parse" to understand why this happens). Change it to `const boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end;`.

Comment: In C++11, you could also do `const boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end{}`